# What are all the changes to apk by AGP 7.1.0?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-bumblebee

I have just upgraded Android Studio from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee and AGP from 7.0.4 to 7.1.0
[image]

The project currently has:
[image]

The apk generated by gradle task assembleOfficialRelease for flavor "official" was in the following directory for many years:

```
..app/build/outputs/apk/official/release/app-official-release.apk
```

I assume it is the new AGP that has changed the location to:

```
..app/build/intermediates/apk/official/release/app-official-release.apk
```

I am trying to find out what else AGP has done to the apk but could not find any in [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle).

I wonder if anyone with insights could tell me what changes the new AGP has done to the apk before I release it to users.

**Update(2022-05-09)**

Android Studio Chipmunk has put the apk file back to the folder ..app/build/outputs/apk/official/release/ without any notification. It killed me a lot of time again before I realized this.

Comment: Yes it is strange. The final release has the same behaviour. Interestingly app bundles still reside under outputs folder.

Comment: The change is fine as long as they have not changed anything of the apk and the only change is file location. I know they have been pushing the bundles but we have good reasons to shun them.

Comment: @Hong This is my guess only.. but when you run the app to install on device. This is not a full app, it only generates APK with ABI of connected device… So it does make sense not to keep it in outputs.. as it is confusing for some devs

Comment: @Sylwek845 I was talking about apk generated by gradle task assembleOfficialRelease, so the apk is not for debugging, but for production deployment. I have not seen any problems so far after publishing them.

Comment: The APK did get a little bit smaller for me when compiled with this gradle version. Hopefully nothing is missing.

Answer (score 7):

I also observed this weird behavior. It seems like if you run the gradle task in Android studio, it will put the apk files in `intermediates`, while if you run the gradle task on command line (at least for bash on Linux), it will put the files in `outputs`.

The canary build of android studio with android gradle plugin 7.3.0-alpha05 seems to solve this issue.