# gradle:7.1.2 assemble can not generate APK file

Tags: android

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

assembleRelease task can not generate apk file in /app/outputs,

If execute bundleRelease ,The bundle file can be generated under the directory as expected;

if change to 7.0.4, everything works fine.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
```

Is this a feature of this version or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apk files are now in `intermediates` folder:

```
..app/build/intermediates/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

See this:
[What are all the changes to apk by AGP 7.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870050/what-are-all-the-changes-changes-to-apk-by-agp-7-1-0)

---EDIT---

Looks back with Gragle 7.2.1 version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
```

Now I have my apk back in `outputs` folder.